# Angular Material - How to change md-tab-link color using md-tab-nav-bar?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Note that this is not for md-tab-group, but the md-tab-nav-bar that can use multiple routes. Here is the basic setup:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link style="border-bottom-color: blue"
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.endpoint"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

As of right now it will default to the primary color (which I've customized as per the official documentation), but I'd like it to show the accent color.

I'm just trying to change the color and there is no documentation on how to do so the correct way in latest Angular 4, and I'm not looking for a hack. There are plenty of SO questions regarding regular tabs but not for this.

Update:
As a workaround / hack I just changed the code to:

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
  <a md-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.endpoint"
     routerLinkActive = "active">
     {{link.label}}
 </a>
</nav>
```

And in SCSS did:

```
.active {
  border-bottom: solid .2em #ffce00;
}
```

But again, I'd really like to do it the correct way.

Comment: I don't know much about Angular Material, but is the "correct way" really to use inline styles in the template? That seems strange. Your workaround/hack looks cleaner and more maintainable to me. If you hadn't written any explanation I would have thought the workaround was the correct way and the other code wasn't!

Comment: To be more helpful though.... 

If you look at the code for that component here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.ts     (starting at line 84 is what is relevant)  It seems that the only options they have built into it are choosing the background color and disabling the ripple effect. I would assume everything else is done via css.

Comment: yeah it may just be one of those things where it either hasn't been implemented or there just isn't any documentation. It is after all one of the newest additions and they only mention it in the documentation since I'm sure they knew people like myself would want a router outlet (which can't be done with tabs). I'll leave this question up so when it does come out then someone can answer and share with us or I'll answer if I find out in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

The latest master build (upcoming in beta.9) supports the `color` and `backgroundColor` options. `color` will change the color of the underline, and `backgroundColor` changes the tab-group or nav-bar background.

[image]